Active window does not redraw
I have Lenovo laptop (model: IdeaPad 5 Pro 16ARH7) with Xubuntu 24.04 installed (AMD cpu and gpu). I'm getting video glitches on some applications (launched using wine mostly but not only). Simple apps, no 3D, etc. 3D games work like a charm.
So, about the problem... Active window does not redraw elements. Elements appears if I minimize window couple times. But they could disappear on any mouse hover or menu dropdown.
Here is screen record: https://youtu.be/yAyr073wH_M
And some screenshots:
Glitch
Glitch2
Normal view
lshw -numeric -C display output:
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Rembrandt [Radeon 680M] [1002:1681]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] [1002]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 mode=2560x1600 resolution=2560,1600 visual=truecolor xres=2560 yres=1600
       resources: iomemory:7e0-7df iomemory:7e0-7df irq:49 memory:7ee0000000-7eefffffff memory:7ef0000000-7ef01fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:c0600000-c067ffff

If you have any solutions or suggestions let me know.
Thanks

Pls run lshw -numeric -C display in a terminal and update your question by editing, It may also be of help if we know model of your computer.

@amar
done, thanks

Do you have anything in "Additional Drivers"? have you ran sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade?

It says "No additional drivers available".
I run apt update and apt upgrade daily but it does not fix the issue.
